# What is a word to describe the place or role which someone takes?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word isn't occupation by the way, however, it is subsumed under the meaning of the word that I am looking for.

I'll give a few examples in order to elucidate the meaning:

> 'The gentleman reserved her ______'
>
> 'By having his uncle murdered, he could take up the long awaited ____ as King of England'.
>
> 'The man asked whether he could take my ____ in line, as his cat was in labour'.

To be precise on what am looking for, it's about someone who has some sort of right to a given position (physical or abstract), of varying degree (from the line at the cheque point, right up unto the throne).

This means that 'place', whilst it does work for all three examples, is not the word am looking for, since you can have a place in say, the middle of the ocean, but no one has right to it (Well to be honest someone probably does for some silly reason).

Comment: May _stead_ be what you mean?

Comment: *Place* works fine in all three of you examples.

Comment: I think “***position***” works fine as well.  “*entitlement*” may have your sense of rights, but taking someone’s spot in line because their cat is in labor doesn’t seem to have any inherent rights associated with it. Maybe it’s a bad example?  perhaps “*rightful position*”  works?

Answer (score 3):

How about *place*? It works well in all of your examples.

> 'The gentleman reserved his *place*.'
>
> 'By having his uncle murdered, he could take up his long awaited
>   *place* as King of England.'
>
> 'The man asked whether he could take my *place* in line, as his cat was
>   in labour.'

M-W:

> [*place*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/place):
>
> - an available seat or accommodation [Example 1]
> - position in a social scale [Example 2]
> - relative position in a scale or series [Example 3]

*Position* also works:

> 'The gentleman reserved his *position*.'
>
> 'By having his uncle murdered, he could take up his long awaited
>   *position* as King of England.'
>
> 'The man asked whether he could take my *position* in line, as his cat was
>   in labour.'

M-W:

[*position*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/position): relative place, situation, or standing; social or official rank or status; a situation that confers advantage or preference

*Position* can also mean the point or area occupied by a physical object. This may speak to your comments about places or locations in the desert or ocean. Positions can also be abstract.

Comment: yes indeed you are correct, however just as occupation is subsumed under the word I am looking for, the word in question is subsumed by the concept of 'place' amongst other things, particularly those places which cannot be owned or reserved,for e.g, a random place in a desert. If one was to be in such a position (literally), one would not say that it's her [word_that_I_am_looking_for]' to describe her being in that patch of desert, not in the same way you would say 'the gentleman reserved her [word_that_I_am_looking_for]'.

Comment: @user108262 I'm just going by your examples. Perhaps you need to add more.

Comment: No no it's not the number of examples, I think the issue lies in the definition itself. I'll make it more clear :)

Comment: Entitlement could mean other things than position, though, like to an item. So one could be entitled to inheritance, but it's not something that one occupies.

Comment: @user108262 Your question is unclear to me. Are you looking for *position*? It works in all three examples also.

Answer (score 0):

**stead**

The place or role that someone or something should have or fill (used in referring to a substitute)

(from Oxford)

---

1 [obsolete] locality, place

2 advantage —used chiefly in the phrase to stand one in good stead

3 the office, place, or function ordinarily occupied or carried out by someone or something else

(from Merriam Webster)

Comment: I'd say that's close, only the definition of the word seems to make the person obligated to fill said place/position, but rather than say that, I'd rather say that they are entitled to it, or have rights to it in some way. So there's a feeling of ownership.

Answer (score 0):

Although I support *place*, I will offer another word that works in the first two examples:

*seat*

< 2. a. A place in which one may sit: found a seat on the floor.
b. The right to occupy such a place or a ticket indicating this right: got seats for the concert.

(Freedictionary.com)

Answer (score 0):

You could use **station** if you weren't too concerned about being misunderstood. [Merriam-Webster Online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/station) has the following definitions among many others:

> 1a)   *The place or position in which something or someone stands or is assigned to stand or remain*
>
> 5)   *standing, rank {eg a woman of high station}*

Definition 1a) could be used for the first and third examples (though it wouldn't really be idiomatic any more) but definition 5) would suit the second example very well.